# Mean of a particular column in combination of csv files

Tags: r, loops, lapply, mean

I am really novice at R. Will appreciate any help I can get.

I have a number of files which I need to combine as one data frame and then get mean of either column 2 or 3. I have tried out but I feel I am making some silly mistake or it might be entirely wrong.

```
polmean <- function(directory, pol, id = 1:3) {
     Dataframe <- function (id) {
             Filenames <- list.files (pattern = "*.csv")
             Reqfiles <- Filenames [id]
             LoadReqfiles <- lapply(Reqfiles, read.csv)
             }
     x <- Dataframe (id)
     Colomnmeans <- function (pol, removeNA = TRUE) {             
             means <- 0
             if (pol == "sulfate") {
             means <- mean (x[,2], na.rm = removeNA)
             } else {
             means <- mean (x[,3], na.rm = removeNA)
             }
              means
             }
     Colomnmeans (pol, removeNA = TRUE)
     }
```

This is giving me an error:  x [,2] incorrect number of dimensions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are making couple of mistakes here.
Mistake#1: The function `Dataframe` is not returning a value. (see below)
Mistake#2: When you use `lapply`, the result is a list. Hence, `x` is a `list` of data frames (and not a `?data.frame`). So you won't be able to access different columns of the list of data frames. You'll have to loop over the data frames.

So try this one:

```
polmean <- function(directory, pol, id = 1:3) {
  Dataframe <- function (id) {
    Filenames <- list.files(directory,pattern=".csv",full.names=TRUE)
    Reqfiles <- Filenames[id]
    LoadReqfiles <- lapply(Reqfiles, read.csv)
    return(LoadReqfiles)  # Mistake1: Need to return the value
  }
  x <- Dataframe(id)
  Colomnmeans <- function (pol, removeNA = TRUE) {             
    means <- NULL
    if (pol == "sulfate") {
      for(i in 1:length(x)) means <- c(means,x[[i]][,2])      
    } else {
      for(i in 1:length(x)) means <- c(means,x[[i]][,3])
    }
    mean(means, na.rm = TRUE)
  }
  Colomnmeans(pol, removeNA = TRUE)
}
```

Note that in the code above, I am using the initialization value as `NULL`, which is a zero length vector. Try:

```
length(NULL)
```

So this won't mess with the function of `mean`, as opposed to using the initialization value of `0`.

Hope this helps!!